# ngrx + protractor - race condition

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, ngrx

I have an issue with my application that only becomes apparent when I run the e2e tests (protractor). In my guard, I have 2 API calls via a service.

What happens is that `whenStable` is called before the data is on the screen. I had initially thought it was a Protractor issue, but it seems not.

Guard code:

```
  getTestData(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.testService
      .callApiA()
      .pipe(
        map( data => new TestStartAction({value: data })),
        tap(action => this.store.dispatch(action)),
        map(Boolean)
      );
  }

  getTestData2(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.testService
      .callApiB()
      .pipe(
        map( kase => new TestStartAction({value: data })),
        tap(action => this.store.dispatch(action)),
        map(Boolean)
      );
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getTestData()
      .pipe(
        switchMap( () => this.getTestData2() )
      );
  }
```

When I run the application everything loads and displays fine. However, when I run the e2e tests the expect is called too early before any data is displayed ( i can see that it does load correctly). It seems there is some sort of race condition (very rarely it passes). Also, the larger the payload the more likely the failure.

I need to make multiple calls because I require the data from the first API before using the next API.

Has anyone experience an issue like this with ngrx 4, Angular 5 and protractor?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something else than `switchMap`. In your particular case I think `canActivate` emits as either `getTestData1()` or `getTestData2()` emits. So your data won't be loaded on completion.

The docs say:

> Be careful though, you probably want to avoid switchMap in scenarios where every request needs to complete.

=> https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

`concat` is what you want here.

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.getTestData()
  .pipe(concat(this.getTestData2()));
}
```

The other problem I see here, is that `getTestData()`and `getTestData2()` emit as `store.dispatch(action)` has finished. But that only means the action is triggered. The effects and the execution of the action are maybe not done yet.